# Portforwarding issue - cannot access from outside router

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm running a server on my local PC on port 8080. I can go to a browser and do http://localhost:8080 and it works.

I'll refer to my public IP as PUBLIC_IP and private/internal as PRIVATE_IP.

In the browser (running on server PC), I can also do http://PUBLIC_IP:8080 and http://PRIVATE_IP:8080 and both work.

I set up port forwarding in the router software as:

TCP external port 8080 >> internal port 8080 to my PRIVATE_IP device.

When I go to canyouseeme.org and enter my PUBLIC_IP and 8080 - I get:

"Error: I could not see your service on PUBLIC_IP on port (8080)"

I looked at the router logs and see:

[LAN access from remote] from 52.202.215.126:55574 to INTERNAL_IP:8080

I assume 52.202.215.126 is the ip address of canyouseeme.org server.

But it seems to be using port 55574 - instead of 8080. And it also changes on each request.

That's the external port that the router sees right?

But looks like the request is getting to the router - just not to my server - getting blocked?

I've turned firewalls off.

Any help appreciated.

Here's the `tcldump` logs - running on the server PC - so traffic is getting to the server PC.

```
Fulls-Mac-mini:conf mini$ sudo tcpdump 'tcp port 8080'
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on pktap, link-type PKTAP (Apple DLT_PKTAP), capture size 262144 bytes
16:08:26.451497 IP ec2-52-202-215-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com.48092 > 192.168.1.12.http-alt: Flags [S], seq 3119124296, win 26883, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 298290090 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:08:26.451570 IP 192.168.1.12.http-alt > ec2-52-202-215-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com.48092: Flags [S.], seq 449444859, ack 3119124297, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 683632630 ecr 298290090,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:08:27.449719 IP ec2-52-202-215-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com.48092 > 192.168.1.12.http-alt: Flags [S], seq 3119124296, win 26883, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 298290340 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:08:27.449751 IP 192.168.1.12.http-alt > ec2-52-202-215-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com.48092: Flags [S.], seq 449444859, ack 3119124297, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 683633624 ecr 298290340,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:08:28.453107 IP 192.168.1.12.http-alt > ec2-52-202-215-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com.48092: Flags [S.], seq 449444859, ack 3119124297, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 683634624 ecr 298290340,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:08:29.453652 IP ec2-52-202-215-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com.48092 > 192.168.1.12.http-alt: Flags [S], seq 3119124296, win 26883, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 298290841 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:08:29.453700 IP 192.168.1.12.http-alt > ec2-52-202-215-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com.48092: Flags [S.], seq 449444859, ack 3119124297, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 683635624 ecr 298290841,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

My internal IP address is 192.168.1.12

The log is a result of https://www.canyouseeme.org/ using my public ip address + 8080.

When I look at Tomcat logs access file - there's no entry. So either it's refusing connection (and not listing it in the logfile) or it's not getting to Tomcat.

Comment: How did you check whether the request is getting to your server or not?

Comment: If I try from outside the local network - no it's not getting there. Looking at the router log file - the fact that the inbound port # is not what I set (i.e. 8080) and it changes - I think is causing it not to match the port-forwarding rule.

Comment: In the router software - for the log file - I enabled just PORT FORWARDING and attempt a connect from outside and it listed an entry - so I'm assuming it's getting forwarded. But I dont see a log file entry in the server. It's a TOMCAT server.

Comment: Install a packet capture tool (Wireshark or tcpdump) on the server and check that way.

Comment: ok just installed wireshark - i have to figure it out - gonna be a while before I make sense of it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, the connection attempt is correct.

Each TCP packet **has two ports:** source and destination, which can also be called local and remote. (So the connections don't go "through" a port; instead they go from one port at the sender, to a possibly different port at the recipient.)

The 'source' port is almost always chosen at random (to ensure that each connection has a unique port *pair*).

The port you see specified in URLs, port-forwarding rules, etc. is almost always the 'destination' port. (This applies to *both* the "external" and "internal" ports when doing NAT..) You've forwarded port 8080, and CanYouSeeMe is also making a connection to port 8080 on your side – so that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks - I tested using my phone on it's own network and I was seeing the same log entries. So I think the port forwarding is working (see above comment) - but the TOMCAT server doesn't seem to be getting it. If I do a in network connection it works.

Comment: The hosts have to exchange _several_ packets back-and-forth after the log message but before the request is actually sent. You haven't checked what happens in between. So install a packet capture tool on the server and take a look at what it's receiving. Add the tcpdump or Wireshark logs in your main post.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Tomcat server port to 8081 and it worked!

Not sure why 8080 wasn't working.