# Cannot connect to Tomcat server from outside network

Tags: tomcat

I cannot connect to my Apache [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) server from outside network.

I can do a localhost:8080 from a browser and it returns a page. I can also use the internal and public ip addresses and it works - from same pc..i.e. same network.

But when I do public_ip:8080 from a different network - it doesn't connect.

I believe I've set port forwarding correctly - I can see it in the logs.

Is there a TOMCAT setting to allow connections from outside network?

Comment: What OS are you running? When you say "from same pc..i.e. same network", did you try it from another system on the same network or only from the same host?  Does your host have IP filters active? Did you look at the config-file for Tomcat (especially the "address="-line in the connector string?

Comment: The server is on MacOS. I tried from the same Mac as well as another Windows PC connected to the same network. Both internal ip and public ip w/ 8080 suffixed work. Did you mean the conf/server.xml - there's no address attribute that's currently set.

Comment: In server.xml - for the `Connector` element, I did set address to "0.0.0.0" - restarted server. No changes.

Comment: If the Tomcat server is accessible from the Windows PC on the same network, then the configuration of the Tomcat server should be OK. That means, that there is some issue on the network. I am a bit surprised that you wrote "Both internal ip and public ip w/ 8080 suffixed work", because the public IP lives on the outside of your router. If the public IP works, that suggests that port forwarding is OK also. Does your ISP do some filtering?

Comment: In my other thread - I posted a `tcpdump` of when I try to access the server from outside the network. The dump is on the server PC. So looks like something is getting to the server. https://superuser.com/questions/1532500/portforwarding-issue-cannot-access-from-outside-router

Comment: If the ISP was filtering the request from outside the network - I wouldn't see the entry in the router logs right? But I do see it and also `tcpdump` shows something - nothing in the `Tomcat` logs though.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the Tomcat server port to 8081 and it worked!

Not sure why 8080 wasn't working.